# When click a div others function disabled?

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

```
<div id="element1" onclick="change();">1</div>
<div id="element2" onclick="change();">2</div>
<div id="element3" onclick="change();">3</div>
```

When click element1 process change function and others onclick function not work. How can I do this with jquery?

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. Since JavaScript is single threaded, no two event handlers can run at the same time anyway.

Comment: Ok I actually want this; when user click any div, change() function work. A counter calculate how many time process change() function and for example if it has run 2 time, when user click any div change() function not work again. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function which only runs once.

Ex:

```
$('#element1,#element2,#element3').one("click", function() {
  console.log("This will be displayed only once.");
})
```

This would also allow you to remove the inline JavaScript you have for cleaner code.